# Does Deadpool know he is breaking the 4th wall?

Tags: deadpool

I've heard some conflicting information as to why Deadpool breaks the 4th wall, especially regarding whether it's deliberate or not.

One side I've heard:

*Deadpool knows that he's in a Marvel comic book and that he doesn't exist in real life, so he breaks the 4th wall constantly because of this.*

He knows he's part of a comic written by writers from Marvel, and so he deliberately breaks the 4th wall due to this. The key thing is that he knows that he's completely fictional.

The other side I've heard:

*Deadpool doesn't know he's in a comic book.  He thinks he's a "comic book hero" due to his insanity, so the "Merc with a Mouth" breaks the 4th wall thinking that's what he should be doing (ironically being that he actually does break the 4th wall)*

Thus, everytime he breaks the 4th wall it is only his persona causing him to do so, as opposed to something the writer added in. Thus, it's somewhat paradoxical in that, while he does break the 4th wall, he only does so because he thinks he's actually in a comic book so because of that he attempts to break the 4th wall anyways much to the chagrin of his fellow superheroes.

Basically, my question boils down to, **does Deadpool THINK he's breaking the 4th wall, or does Deadpool KNOW he's breaking the 4th wall**?

Comment: What's breaking the fourth wall to some is insanity to others.

Comment: This explanation is so meta: [4th Wall Awareness](http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/4th_Wall_Awareness)

Comment: I'm not sure I see the difference between the cases you're asking about. In both of them, he *believes* he is a comic book character, the other comic book characters *believe* that he isn't, and we *know* that they all are.

Comment: @DCShannon Clarified the question a bit more

Comment: As a teenager, I went through a short phase where I didn't exactly believe that I *was* trapped in some comic book or Truman Show style dystopia, but I did believe that it was a possibility worth addressing. So whenever I was on my own or no-one was looking, and either I did something stupid or some suspiciously unlikely twist or drama happened around me, I'd look towards whatever looked like the best angle to film this scene from, and roll my eyes or give a "come on, seriously" expression. I didn't think there *was* anyone watching, but *just in case there was*, it seemed worth it...

Comment: ...so I guess you could say what's breaking the fourth wall or insanity to some, is a rational response to a world full of uncertainties and unknowns to others...

Comment: This 4th wall stuff is way to deep... Making my had spin.

Comment: Deadpool can't just *think* that he's breaking the wall, because he *is*. So if he believes that he is, then he *knows* that he is, because it's true.

Comment: @DCShannon: It's a [Gettier problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettier_problem)!

Comment: @user568458 That's ... I can't even ...

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://www.simulation-argument.com/simulation.html).

Comment: Pascal's paradox on steroids.

Comment: @user568458: Mandatory xkcd reference: https://xkcd.com/525/ .

Comment: @user568458 I remember when you did that, it was awesome.  Freaked out a couple of the presenters but that was okay.  Good luck with tomorrows show.

Comment: Deadpool does not actually break the fourth wall. We are all a figment of His imagination.

Comment: Deadpool's got the most powerful power in all Marvel Universe: _Comic Awareness_

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Deadpool intentionally breaks the fourth wall because he's aware that he's fictional.** He just doesn't realize what that means until the events of [Deadpool Kills the Marvel Universe](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Deadpool_Kills_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_1_1).

In that story, Deadpool is sent to an asylum where Psycho-Man attempts to brainwash him. This fails rather spectacularly as it instead silences his old voices and awakens a new one which starts him on a killing spree.

[image: start]

[**Major story spoilers follow**]

While murdering his way through the entire Marvel cast of heroes and villains it's gradually revealed that he's become fully aware of his fictional nature and believes these to be mercy killings. It's mentioned that he's always seen the reality of his fictional world but never understood it until his run-in with Psycho-Man.

[image: reveal]

Xavier attempts to stop Deadpool by accessing his mind whereupon he realises the truth as well, going mad in the process.

[image: mindbreak]

It's implied that Deadpool has always seen through the fourth wall but was powerless to do more than the writers let him, until the events of this story where he broke free of their control.

[image: free]

Eventually, he makes his way to the [Nexus of All Realities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWV3q.jpg) where he crosses dimensions/planes/realities to the "real world", where the story comes full circle in the final panel:

> [image: Finale of DKTMU]

*Note: I'm unaware of what is and isn't considered canon when it comes to Marvel. The claims made by The Watcher indicate that this is what happened in one of the many coexisting realities, implying that the revelations made about Deadpools insight into the fourth wall are true in most of them.*

Comment: I would make one point here.  Notice the first sentence **"because he's aware that he's fictional..."**.  Note: Deadpool *is NOT fictional*.  I don't mean that in some deep philosophical sense:  "MASH" is not fictional, it's a real TV show.  "Cosmos with Carl Sagan" was not fictional, it's a real TV show.  Deadpool is as completely real as the CBS Evening News or Seinfeld or Superman. In contrast the (nonexistent, fictional) TV show which Mary Tyler Moore produces does not exist. (But "Mary Tyler Moore" of course exists - she is a famous TV character.) ...

Comment: ...  Deadpool knows he is a (real) famous media character.  Whereas say Superman has no clue he is a (real) famous media character. It would be quite different if Deadpool was "just made up" (and realised that was the case).  Deadpool is actually Deadpool .. like Cosmos or MASH or Superman ..  and he knows it.

Comment: "I'LL FIND YOU SOON ENOUGH." Oh snap, RUN!

Comment: @JoeBlow: the entity you're referring to when you say, "Deadpool is as completely real as the CBS Evening News" is not an entity of a type to which the sentence "Deadpool knows X" can be true. Similarly, the CBS evening news cannot know something. MASH cannot know something. The letter Q cannot know something. This is the disparity that the authors are playing on.

Comment: But I'm not sure if that's true, Steve.  It's a completely open question if an organism like "Apple" "knows anything".  (If you think "John knows something" .. what's the difference between "some humans and desks" (Apple) and "some atoms in a skull" (John).)  It's like the chinese room argument, you know...  quite a puzzle!

Comment: BTW re the original question, **"is Deadpool [a crackpot who] THINK's he's breaking the 4th wall, or does Deadpool KNOW [correctly who he is and that he's] breaking the 4th wall?"**  Based on the many excellent examples above, it seems to be very much the former.  He's very lucid and correct, and it's presented as if he is correct.  In all events this is a **fantastic question, thanks!**

Comment: @JoeBlow No, there's an idea of Deadpool, which is as "real" as any other idea.  And there are physical artifacts people have created under it.  Each artifact (but not its content) is real individually, however that doesn't make the idea(s) that they reference real.  There's no corresponding entity.  Real things exist whether or not ideas describe them.  MASH isn't a real anything, but real materials do exist that describe fictitious events set up with certain parameters that make "MASH" a useful shorthand way of referring to that collection.  But that's all it is; a shorthand reference.

Comment: But wait, doesn't that last frame prove that the writers are still controlling him? Maybe the writers dropped acid and killed themself, suicide by deadpool

Comment: Fiction can sometimes take a life of its own. Anyone who's written a novel knows that you can have a plan that doesn't survive long because of who the characters are the nature of the events. Your understanding of the characters evolves as you write, and so they might just act differently to what you planned. In this comic Deadpool is really acting as he *would act* unrestrained, rather than the writers reigning him in, making him act unlike himself. If that makes sense.

Comment: @klskl That depends on whether you think the last panel is taking place in the comic or in the "real world", whichever that may be. I was racking my brain over that ending for a while before I took a page out of Deadpool's (comic) book and simply stopped thinking about it so hard.

Comment: "the writers are still controlling him" ... and note that, straight away you have the sort of "corporate being" concept coming in to play.  Imagine if all of the writers who have ever worked on Deadpool, passed away: of course there'd just be more writers, different production companies (this happens all the time).  So straight away the idea of the "writers controlling him" is a fuzzy concept.  Tricky!

Comment: ... Deadpool is forever. Deadpool is Life.

Answer (score 62):

Deadpool is aware that he's a character in comic books, so when he breaks the fourth wall, it's intentional.  Here's a few examples...

**Deadpool finds out he's in a comic**
[image]

**Deadpool acknowledges he's in a comic**
[image: Deadpool acknowledges he's in a comic]

**Deadpool makes reference to the people reading the comic**
[image: Deadpool makes reference to the people reading the comic]

**Deadpool directly addresses the reader**
[image: Deadpool directly addresses the reader]

Comment: That last comic looks like it was drawn by Dr. McNinja's artist.

Comment: To be fair, the recap page is kind of out of scope, isn't it? @Axelrod FYI: It's [Deadpool by Posehn & Duggan Volume 1](http://www.amazon.de/dp/0785154469) IIRC

Comment: Possibly, but I was just showing reference to him acknowledging the fourth wall

Comment: @Axelrod Chris Hastings (Dr. McNinja's comic creator) is/was for some time now working on Deadpool for Marvel.

Comment: @Mindwin That would explain a few things (Like Ben Franklin). Good. Deadpool looks better as a skinny guy, rather than a brick wall.

Comment: Was going to post something like this but this does it fine.

Comment: The only really good evidence here is the "issue 16.  Greece" quote.  If the character was insane and thought he was in a comic (separately from the fact that there is a comic about this character), he wouldn't know which issue number.  Thinking that it's a good time to explain something to readers doesn't prove it one way or the other.

Answer (score 55):

What would be the difference between a Deadpool who, in his insanity, *thinks* he's part of a comic book, or a Deadpool who, in his insanity, is *aware* that he's part of a comic book?

Accuracy.

To put it another way, if someone told me they could predict the lottery results, and then they continually and accurately predict the lottery results, they probably can. Deadpool's observations mesh with reality: when he declares that something happened in issue 16, it happened in issue 16.

If Deadpool wasn't aware, if he was just deluded, then he would still be saying the same sorts of things, but the numbers wouldn't mesh. He wouldn't know which direction the fourth wall was in. He would be wrong, not in HIS universe, but in OURs.

Comment: What an outstanding point.

Comment: Interesting story idea: A character in a fiction story addresses an "audience" from time to time, but the character is facing the *wrong direction* when they do this and are actually imagining a whole different audience from the real audience. Or are they...?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Final panel, he turns and winks at the REAL audience?

Comment: I should add, an alternate explanation would be that Deadpool, in his insanity, INCORRECTLY thinks he's part of a comic book, and WE exist solely as part of his delusion -- but since the notion that we all exist only as a quirk of the subconscious of an murderous mouthy mercenary wasn't part of the original question, I restricted myself to the more pertinent possibilities.

Comment: @ToddWilcox breaking the fifth wall?

Answer (score 20):

### It's a postmodern thing.

The story itself is an intellectual construct. The writers have one of the characters in the construct become aware of the bounds of the construct, but it's funny because Deadpool of course doesn't exist, so he is incapable of realising anything.

The writers then have Deadpool break through the bounds of the construct, implying that the reality they are creating is, in a sense, as valid as any other reality, including the one which we inhabit.

The ultimate implication is that our existence is a construct, and that the reality we perceive is one that is created, either by us, or for us. It's designed to twist our notions of what is real, which of course makes us laugh because it's amusing to blur the lines of reality.

Comment: Quite right.  Note though ... *"because Deadpool of course doesn't exist..."* That's a very difficult concept.  Consider "The president of the United States." (I don't mean "Bill Clinton" or other humans, I mean "The president of the United States.")  Of course, that thing **obviously does not "exist"** in any meaningful way.  It's just some words. Of course, that thing **obviously does "exist"** in meaningful ways.  We don't even know if, say, "integers" exist.  "Deadpool" has had far, far more influence on the planet (for example) than myself.  The question of existence if subtle.

Comment: @JoeBlow You're being a bit pedantic :) Most people understand the difference between "exist" as in "this exists as a sentient entity capable of knowing or believing things" vs "this is something that exists as a concept". Bill Clinton and Deadpool's writers are sentient and capable of being aware of things; Deadpool and the role of POTUS aren't aware of anything because they are not sentient.  Deadpool also doesn't exist as a real person. This is what everyone means when they say Deadpool is "fictional" or that he "doesn't exist". It's just that we take shortcuts with our wording!

Comment: @JoeBlow "Consider 'The president of the United States.' (I don't mean 'Bill Clinton'...)" Er, we need to talk. You've been sleeping for fifteen years. Maybe twenty. Don't worry. It'll be OK.

Comment: Actually @joeblow makes an important point. 'President' is a term that we have invented. It's a collective narrative, so it exists only in so far as the stories we tell ourselves about the world exist.

Comment: right, that example is from one of Douglas Hofstaeder's books, as I recall.

Comment: Reality is more valid because it isn't ownable. Has Deadpool made reference to the publisher's copyright yet?

Answer (score 8):

As Deadpool is indeed playing the role of a hero in a comic book, the two options you propose are both sides of a same coin.

In the comic, Deadpool constantly violates the 4th wall rule because he's aware of being a character in a fictional work.

This resource has been used by authors for centuries in almost any art form where a 4th wall is involved (primarily theatre, tv, cinema, comic and books, but you can also find examples in painting, photography, sculpture or even music in certain operas, etc...)

So... he do it. And he does it because he knows (or believes) that he's a fictional character.

The fact is that he ACTUALLY is a fictional character. So even if an author wants to play the card that he's mad and believing something that's false you, as an spectator, are being fooled, as the thing that the author is trying to hide from you is ACTUALLY happening.

Comment: Is there a source that shows that Deadpool actually knows he's fictional? Or is it that he believes that, since he believes he is a comic book character, then he thinks he's fictional (even though he's still fictional)

Comment: The key is that doesn't matters if he knows or just believes that he's fictional, because he IS fictional. If he knows it's ok, and if he believes it, you're being cheated by the author, as he actually is fictional.

Comment: "The fact is that he ACTUALLY is a fictional character." Says who... him? Can we believe a fictional character when he says he's fictional? Sounds suspiciously what a real character pretending to be fictional would do...

Comment: Says who? Me, I have a comic book depicting him, I know he's fictional in real life, that's what I'm talking about.

Comment: this does not actually answer the question of the distinction between the two in the OP.

Comment: In fact it does, just maybe is not the expected response

Comment: @Bardo While it's an interesting point, the fact that he is correct in believing he's fictional doesn't mean that he *knows* he's fictional.  He must also (at least) have a good reason to believe it, in order for what he has to be generally understood as "knowledge".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justified_true_belief#Justified_true_belief

Answer (score 6):

"He knows he doesn't exist" is an interesting statement since it is a direct contradiction to Descartes' *cogito ergo sum*. One cannot know anything without thinking. If he doesn't exist then he doesn't think or know anything, says Descartes. "Shut the f**k up, yes I do think, and anyway you're just some dead a-hole", says Deadpool.

A large part of the point of the whole routine is to subvert the notion that *any* fictional character, including those in Marvel's works, exists, or has knowledge or beliefs, or speaks, or takes actions. *Deadpool* (the work rather than the character) challenges the convenient notion of referring to in-fiction or in-canon information as "facts", because it intentionally confuses the issue of what things we're talking about when we make these statements of fact. If reading a Marvel comic actually is observing the Marvel universe, then what absurdities emerge when we consider how that universe could interact with this one?

So personally I think the only sensible short answer to "does Deadpool THINK he's breaking the 4th wall, or does Deadpool KNOW he's breaking the 4th wall?" is "well, exactly".

That is one of the things you're supposed to think about, and there is not a clear-cut answer because another of the things you're supposed to think about is the invalidity of the assumption that there *can* be clear-cut in-fiction answers to questions about fictional characters. Sorry fans (says Marvel), *there is no such place as the Marvel Universe*. You can make true statements about works of fiction set in the Marvel Universe (or any ficton, such as MCU) but strictly speaking you cannot make true statements about the fictional "entities themselves" even though that is exactly the shorthand we use when talking about fiction -- "is this true in canon?" etc.

On the surface of it, the difference between "belief" and "knowledge" depends on *exactly* what you construe the word "knowledge" to mean, and the field of philosophy that attempts to define knowledge is called epistemology. It is not easy. There's a classical definition that knowledge is a "true, justified, belief". This has some problems and is *not* generally considered by philosophers to be an adequate definition, but will probably suffice as a necessary but not sufficient condition. So, is Deadpool's belief that he is fictional both "justified" and "true"?

It's certainly true "up here" in the real world. Deadpool is a fictional character. But up here in the real world Deadpool doesn't exist as a person, and doesn't "believe" anything. So that true statement is not a belief held by Deadpool. Down there in the ficton he holds beliefs, but it's not clear whether or not it's true down there in the ficton that he doesn't exist. All of our usual instincts scream that he *does* exist in the ficton, and therefore in the ficton his belief that he doesn't exist is *incorrect*. But the writers make it so plausible. Then, the comic intentionally nests fictons in order to further confuse the issue. So probably it isn't "knowledge" since it fails the "truth" criterion *except* when you mix and match two different contexts (reality and the Marvel ficton), between which statements like "Deadpool can think" and "Deadpool is a person" have different truth values, and between which the statement "Deadpool exists" mean different things.

As a side note, interesting consequences of treating "existence" as a property of a hypothetical entity, alongside other properties we might ascribe to hypothetical entities, were first explored in the Western tradition by Saint Anselm when he presented in 1078 the "ontological argument" for the existence of God. This is not a novel quandary ;-)

As for whether it passes the "justified" criterion: you can look for clues in the fiction as to whether (a) he is insane, and breaks the fourth wall in a "random" direction, but the "cameraman" intentionally places the "camera" in *just the right place* to make him accidentally correct, or (b) he has followed a reasonable logical process to conclude that he's fictional based on observations he makes. But to do this is to miss the message that *this whole process of reasoning within the ficton is intentionally subverted by the work you're reading*. Deadpool and the "world" he appears to inhabit behave as the authors cause them to behave, and the authors make this more obvious than usual. The ficton does not necessarily have to behave according to logical consequences of "facts" like "Deadpool is delusional" or "Deadpool is not delusional".

Seriously, the whole point is to bake your noodle, there is not supposed to be a correct answer. The reason "Deadpool breaks the fourth wall" is that artists, following the instructions of writers, draw self-referential pictures that depict a man making statements about the pictures. The reason these pictures are *interesting* has to do with how we experience fiction.