# Is movie Deadpool's fourth wall breaking a "mutant power"?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016, deadpool-2

In the first *Deadpool* movie, Deadpool gains his powers as part of attempting to force a mutation. And he does get a mutation: the incredible healing factor. He also gains the ability to break the fourth wall and recognize he's in a comic book movie some time shortly after the mutation.

However, neither movie is really clear on whether his ability to see and interact with the audience was a literal mutant power, a side effect of him going insane from the therapy, or just a running joke that isn't bound by logic.

Comment: As far as I know, Deadpool wasn't born with any powers, which means he's officially a mutate, not a mutant. So, arguably, he can't have mutant powers, only mutate powers. I know I'm being pedantic here, which is why this isn't an actual answer, just a small clarification for the sake of accuracy.

Comment: Maybe in the movies that fact is not clear, but in the comics, however, IT IS actually a superpower, as is explained in this [related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121781/how-does-deadpool-break-the-4th-wall/121797#121797)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

After reviewing the script again from the advice of a friend offline, it looks like Wade's 4th wall breaking isn't a power. While he has his collar on, he quips the following while turning and looking directly at the camera:

> Fun fact about the Ice Box... though no one's ever seen it, they keep a monster in the basement. Right next to a huge, steaming bowl of foreshadowing.
>   https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=deadpool-2

So, even when he's powerless, he can still call out movie tropes and recognize that it's a popcorn flick with an audience.

Comment: But surely if his mutant power gave him the _knowledge_ that he was a fictional character in a movie, taking away his power wouldn't take away that knowledge.

Comment: @delinear Maybe, but he wouldn't know where the camera was at that specific time.

Comment: True, although if he knew he was part of a movie he might reasonably expect that if he did a "monologue to camera" thing, a camera _would_ be there to capture it XD

Comment: @delinear It would be fun if he was giving his monologue but he was facing the wrong way.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez yeah if they'd filmed it so that whenever he had his collar on, he kept wrongly guessing where the camera was meant to be. That'd be super meta, but definitely in line with the character!

Comment: @delinear In other words, Deadpool subscribes to a very specific version of the [anthropic principle](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Anthropic_principle#), that the universe was literally made for him. And he's right!

Comment: Also, it should be noted that he did a lot of fourth-wall breaking in the first film as just Wade Wilson, before he got powers from Ajax.

Answer (score 60):

It's not a mutation. It's actually a sign of [his madness](http://deadpool.wikia.com/wiki/Deadpool#Personality). Deadpool gained his powers through torture<sup>1</sup>, which mentally broke him.

Not only is he under the "illusion" (in-universe this is seen as a derangement) that he is a [fictional character](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121615/46407) (his frequent 4th-wall breaks)

> Ryan Reynolds has told Empire that he’s insistent on Deadpool‘s habit of breaking of the fourth wall to carry over from the comics to the big screen. That means, in effect, that Deadpool/Wade Wilson will sometimes address the audience directly, as with Ferris Bueller, say, or the character of Paul in Funny Games.

[Source](https://www.slashfilm.com/movie-deadpool-to-break-fourth-wall-talk-to-the-audience/)

He also suffers from schizophrenia (voices in his head)<sup>2</sup>,

[image]

And while it could be attributed to the excessive amount of pain he undergoes on a regular basis - his reaction to pain and being mutilated over and over again is not one you would expect from a sane person.

---

<sup>1. In Deadpool 1, Ajax explains that the Weapon X program requires the body to undergo increasing amounts of stress in order to trigger the mutation.

2. This is in the comics, but not depicted in the movies. It is possible that this was tied into the 4th wall breaks as talking to the audience as the "voices" in his head</sup>

Comment: The schizophrenia seems to be in the movies too. For example in the first one he has a limited number of bullets left and uses an excessive number to take down one guy who was particularly annoying. He says something like "stupid stupid stupid... worth it", similar to how in the comics each voice gives a different take on events.

Comment: The problem is, he doesn't just believe he's a character in a movie and narrate to an imaginary audience the thoughts in his head, if he did it would be easy to write off. However, he also references accurate information from outside the world of the movie which he has no reasonable way of knowing and which we, the audience, know to be true (like when he asks whether the professor they're going to see is "McAvoy or Stewart", if he was just mentally unstable we'd have to write that off as a ridiculous coincidence, and he does it a _lot_).

Comment: @delinear That's the joke - people in-universe think he's insane, but the audience knows he's right.  That's why "illusion" is in quotes in the answer.

Comment: `"Ajax"`?  Don't you mean Francis?

Comment: It's how I've always seen it. Going insane can very well involve thinking that you are being watched, and talking to imaginary friends. In Deadpool's case, it just happens to be true.

Answer (score 8):

Movies are a little more vague on this but if you include comic lore it is much clearer. So I have read a lot of Deadpool comics and I can tell you he is [fully aware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYhPU.png) that he is in a comic book but it is not derived from his mutant powers whatsoever just a side affect of his craziness. At one point he instructs the readers to update his wiki page to show that he was offered to join the X-Men and refused after Storm asks for his help even.

If you are looking for a character whose power revolves around manipulating the comic book she is in I would recommend the Gwenpool character. The Unbelievable Gwenpool #13 even has [Deadpool and Gwen talking about being in each others books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzLr2.png).

Comment: Can you provide some direct references to support this?

Comment: Ya it was Deadpool (2012) #36.
[Deadpool knows](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e6SsmcJC0pxDy9Ryc5RHZW-OYOp9_am9) he is in a comic.

Comment: @BrettJohnson - I love the tie in with Gwenpool, but this does not "show" that the ability is not related to his superpower and therefore does not technically answer the question. Is there another reference that you know of supporting/proving the idea that either of their wall breaking in the comics is not a superpower?

Comment: Gwenpool's powers are centered around her knowing she is in a comic so I would say her superpower is the ability to break the 4th wall. For Deadpool there is just an absence of any lore ever equating his powers to this knowledge, for him breaking the 4th wall is just something he does. So I would have to just say the complete lack of supporting material around it makes me believe it isn't associated with his forced mutation.

Comment: Just more proof Deadpool is insane.